# gcloud compute ssh can't connect at office's network

Tags: ssh, gcloud

I'm running an instance on google cloud and I can access it normally using:

```
$ gcloud compute ssh instance-2
```

But I've got the following error when I try to access when I'm at office. I've tested rooting my mobile's internet and works fine. I tested on all instances and get the same response. Is that possible a rule that blocks my network in some way? I have a dynamically ip on my office's network.

```
$ gcloud compute ssh instance-2
No zone specified. Using zone [us-central1-c] for instance: [instance-2].
ssh: connect to host xx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection timed out
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible to have outgoing SSH session blocked by your office network's firewall. Are you able to SSH to any other host outside the office network?

Comment: It's also possible to have incoming SSH blocked by the GCE firewall, check with `gcloud compute firewall-rules list`

Comment: @DanCornilescu Yes, I got this problem only at office.

Comment: I have two rules to use ssh, one to allow ingress and another to allow egress: $ gcloud compute firewall-rules list
NAME                                                       NETWORK  DIRECTION  PRIORITY  ALLOW                         DENY
default-allow-ssh                                          default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:22
default-allow-ssh-out                                      default  EGRESS     1000      tcp:22

Comment: I suspect that my problem are related to the router that I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days trying different solutions I finally found the problem.

The office's internet service provider has a setting that an ip number serve multiple clients, I opened a ticket and complained about the fact and they changed it. There are also some limitations in the modem, so I've changed the mode to bridge and connect another router to serve WiFi.